# In Gatling can we insert variable in custom error message

Tags: gatling

In this exemple

```
check(
  status is 200,
  css("title").name("Expected page :: Member Home").is("Member Home")
)
```

How can we use a variable content specified in the session context in the custom error message?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible atm (Gatling 3.5.1), the `name` parameter is a static String, not an `Expression[String]`. Feel free to contribute.

Comment: Thank you your response. I'm not comfortable enough in scala

Comment: Maybe we can do something like this check( status is 200, jsonPath("...")find.name("No contract id " + "${maVariable}").saveAs("contractId") )

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by using `.validate` where you can define your custom error response using your variables and session values.

Documentation: https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/check/#validate